# MySQL replace space+period with period

Tags: mysql, replace

The string value is 
'Naiste kellad: Lacoste kell LK030806 . Garantii 2 aastat. Hind: 302 €.'

I need to replace space+period with period, but the query won't update it:

```
SELECT REPLACE(meta_description, ' .', '.') FROM `ps_product_lang` WHERE meta_description like '% .%' ;
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` SET meta_description=REPLACE(meta_description, ' .', '.') WHERE meta_description like '% .%' ;
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Not reproducting: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZoJrqTe5Ze6uebL5R6Cra/0

Comment: How are you executing these queries? You've provided two, and many db libraries do not allow multiple queries in a single "execute" call.

Comment: Executing separately, the SELECT is just to show it finds matches. As the other poster said, cannot reproduce in the fiddle but it happens in my phpmyadmin. Could it be something encoding/hidden character related? Because it works when selecting ' .' but not when replacing.

Comment: @popkutt ohh, you did not mention about PHPMyAdmin thing. I have noticed that PHPMyAdmin automatically removes leading/trailing spaces in an input string. I might have seen similar behaviour in the MySQL Workbench. You can rather run this query via Terminal, or using the application code.